# Zend Framework 2 (ZF2) - PHPUnit and $this->url()->toRoute() does not work

Tags: url, frameworks, zend-framework2, phpunit

I was reading about ZF 2 (http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html) and I have written a controller Test, but I already have a codified Action in my controller and, if not entered an ID, it directs the user to the indexAction, performing the test with PHPUnit works depending on how I do the redirect example:

```
// Does not Work
return $ this-> redirect () -> toRoute ('my_route', array ('action' => 'index'));
```

Returns the following error message:

> TopAcl\Controller\MY_CONTROLLER_ControllerTest :: testEditarActionCanBeAcessed Zend\Mvc\Router\Exception\RuntimeException: Route with name "my_route" not found

```
// Works correctly
return $ this-> redirect () -> toUrl ('/ resource');
```

I found nothing on the internet about it, is there any explanation? I need some more load file?

```
// Follow the setUp of my ControllerTest:
protected function setUp ()
{
    $ bootstrap = \Zend\Mvc\Application :: init (include 'config/application.config.php');
    $ this-> controller = new ResourceController ();
    $ this-> request = new Request ();
    $ this-> routeMatch = new RouteMatch (array ('controller' => 'index'));
    $ this-> event = $ bootstrap-> getMvcEvent ();
    $ this-> event-> setRouteMatch ($ this-> routeMatch);
    $ this-> controller-> SetEvent ($ this-> event);
    $ this-> controller-> setEventManager ($ bootstrap-> getEventManager ());
    $ this-> controller-> setServiceLocator ($ bootstrap-> getServiceManager ());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the problem:

> toRoute ('my_route', array ('action' => 'index')

I would expect to see configured route in module/Application/config/module.config.php, it's better to keep configuration outside the code

```
return array(
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'my_route' => array(
            'type' => 'Literal',
            .....
```